# Trigger mysql in altervista

Tags: mysql, triggers

i'm using mysql on altervista and i did this trigger but when i try it have "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 ", help pls

```
CREATE TRIGGER  increase
AFTER INSERT ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INTEGER; <---- line 5

    SELECT count(*)
    INTO counter
    FROM tableC;

    IF(counter ==  0) THEN
        UPDATE tableB
        SET num = num + 1;
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [change the delimiter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) - MySQL is seeing the first ";" as the end of the CREATE TRIGGER statement.

Try this:

```
/* Change the delimiter so we can use ";" within the CREATE TRIGGER */
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER increase
BEFORE INSERT ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     DECLARE counter INTEGER;  

    SELECT count(*)
     INTO counter
     FROM tableC;

     IF(counter ==  0) THEN
        UPDATE tableB
       SET num = num + 1;
     END IF;
END$$
/* This is now "END$$" not "END;" */

/* Reset the delimiter back to ";" */
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I change it but it has the same problem "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 "

Comment: use delimiter and try agin